# Detect browser concurrent connection limit programmatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, browser

Is there a way to programmatically detect the browser's maximum concurrent limit in javascript (Reactjs)? both per domain and overall maximum.

I know that there are charts on the net but, I want to be able to get the correct information, in case the stats are not up to date in future updates of those browsers.